# How to solve this error: join() expects at most 2 arguments, 4 given Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display some data on a view from the database using 2 tables. Its a details view which shows data for a particular id. But I want to match a column with another column from another table and show data from the other table on the same view.

Here is how I tried it, but I am getting an error `join() expects at most 2 arguments, 4 given`

```html
function details ($id) {
        $fruit = Fruit::find($id);
                        join('fruit', 'fruit.id', '=', $id);
        $page = "Fruit Details";
        return view('admin.fruits.details', compact('fruit'), ['page'=>$page]);
    }
```

Please Help

Comment: You're using this [join()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join), not the one you think, probably because you forgot to mention the `Fruit::` class.

Comment: You're not using the query builder join because you closed out the query on the line before with `;`, though it wouldn't work anyways because `find()` returns the single object. You're using the [php version of join](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) which is an alias of `implode`. Move the `join` before `find`

Answer (score 1):

As the comments point out you closed the query with the semi-colon so now, `join` is just the [standard PHP join](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) that accepts 2 parameters.

```php
$fruit = Fruit::find($id);
join('fruit', 'fruit.id', '=', $id);
```

There are actually quite a few ways to do joins in Laravel but (IMHO) the most straightforward way is to [use Laravel's Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins).

Your table/model names are a bit confusing but it sounds like you have 2 tables: a parent (I can't see the name from the code you provided) and a child table called `fruit`. I made the assumption that your model Fruit points to a table named `fruit_main`

```php
// Notice the join uses the names of the tables to distinguish the ID columns
$fruit = DB::table('fruit_main')
    ->join('fruit', 'fruit.id', '=', 'fruit_main.id')
    ->where('fruit_main.id', $id)
    ->first();
```